# Исключение типа NullReferenceExeption, где проблема?

Tags: c#, wpf

Генерируется исключение типа

> System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Вот такая у меня разметка `XAML`:

```
<Label x:Name="Label_Seconds" Content="0 секунд" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16"/>
<Slider x:Name="Numbers_Slider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" ValueChanged="Numbers_Slider_ValueChanged" Value="4" UseLayoutRounding="False" Minimum="4" Maximum="6"/>
<Label x:Name="Label_Numbers" Content="4 числа" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" RenderTransformOrigin="0.462,1.355"/>
<Slider x:Name="Seconds_Slider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" ValueChanged="Seconds_Slider_ValueChanged" Value="4" UseLayoutRounding="False" Minimum="4" Maximum="6"/>
```

Вот код С#:

```
private void Numbers_Slider_ValueChanged( object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e )
{
    // Здесь Label_Numbers == null
    Label_Numbers.Content = $"{Numbers_Slider.Value.ToInt32 ( )} числа";
}

private void Seconds_Slider_ValueChanged( object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e )
{
    Label_Seconds.Content = $"{Seconds_Slider.Value} секунды";
}
```

А теперь к вопросу. По задумке, должен меняться текст `Label` в зависимости от значения слайдера. Но не тут то было. При первом запуске было все нормально, но потом нарисовал второй такой слайдер и тут же выбрасывает исключение. Где проблема и почему все таки `Label_Numbers = null`

Comment: Ну вы знаете, куда мы отправляем вопросы с Null reference.

Comment: @AK ду-бли-кат.

Comment: *Вот такой у меня XML* — это называется **разметка XAML**, а не просто XML

Comment: На какой строчке ошибка? И проверьте всё-таки под отладчиком какая конкретно переменная равна null

Comment: Label_Seconds = null

Comment: правил вопрос по правкам

Comment: Заголовок точно нормальный?

Comment: Понятно в чём трабл. Ща напишу ответ.

Comment: @SeeSharp а хотя погоди, у тебя проблема в Label_Seconds? Просто у меня она возникла в Label_Numbers и я понял почему...

Comment: Прикольно, никогда не сталкивался с такой ошибкой, поменяйте в приведенной разметке вторую и третью строчку местами

Comment: Не знаю просто придерайтесь вы или просто так надо и т.д. Но оформление вопроса в частности опечатка особо на решение его не влияет. Да вопрос *В какой строчке исключение* нормально но остальные..

Comment: А в первом методе всегда неважно с какой переменной роботаем

Comment: какой выше там и исключение

Comment: Либо подписывайтесь на события не в XAML, а в конструкторе после `InitializeComponent`, когда все имена уже точно разрешены

Comment: А да извините опечатался в 'Label_Numbers` исключение только там

Comment: @АндрейNOP тут ты прав. ошибка в порядке создания элементов.

Comment: Так что делать?

Comment: пиши в ответ @АндрейNOP получилось в конструкторе подписался на событие

Comment: @SeeSharp А ничего, что у вас Label для секунд находится над слайдером для числа, а Label для числа - над слайдером для секунд? У вас тут с самого начала ошибка в оформлении. Если бы вы правильно написали, то и ошибки бы не было)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше всего в вашем случае подписываться на события после того как все элементы уже точно инициализированы:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Numbers_Slider.ValueChanged += Numbers_Slider_ValueChanged;
    Seconds_Slider.ValueChanged += Seconds_Slider_ValueChanged;
}
```

А из разметки подписку убрать.

Дело в том, что интерпретатор XAML читает документ сверху вниз и при установке слайдеру свойства `Value` сразу срабатывает событие `ValueChanged`, но `Label_Numbers` здесь еще не существует, т.к. описан ниже, поэтому и возникает NRE.

Можно, конечно, поместить определение `Label_Numbers` в разметке выше `Numbers_Slider`, но это ненадежное решение.

---

А вообще, в WPF этот пример можно (и нужно) сделать вообще без подписки на события — с использованием механизма привязок. Также вам необходимо отказаться от "рисования контролов мышкой" и писать разметку вручную, активно используя панели компоновки (да, с ними надо ознакомиться, но их не много и знакомство с ними быстрое):

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,2.5,0,2.5"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Slider">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Slider Name="Seconds_Slider" Value="4" Minimum="4" Maximum="6"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=Seconds_Slider, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0.##} секунд}"/>

    <Slider Grid.Row="1" Name="Numbers_Slider" Value="4" Minimum="4" Maximum="6"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=Numbers_Slider, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0.##} числа}"/>
</Grid>
```

Да, разметка вышла более громоздкая за счет выноса одинакового форматирования в стиль, но когда контролов станет гораздо больше, эта громоздкость нивелируется, также стили можно вынести в отдельный словарь ресурсов или в App.xaml. Вынос оформления в стиль разгружает основную разметку — в ней остается только то что существенно здесь и сейчас, оформление же получается тоже скомпонованным в одном месте.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли)

Comment: @SeeSharp, дополнил ответ.

Comment: А как мне вынести стили в App.xaml. Не могу разобраться. Буду благодарен за дополнение самую малость в ответ.

Comment: Ну как, открываете тег `Application.Resources` и помещаете стили туда.

Comment: Все спасибо. Просто у меня там ещё локализация, и не мог понять куда пихать стили.